# Why there's no reaction about Saudi Arabia criminal actions?

Tags: armed-conflict, united-nations, saudi-arabia

We see that Saudi regime is spreading criminal actions among Muslims. Founding bastards of ISIS terrorist group, Founding Al-Shabab terroris group, Massacre in Bahrain, War in Yemen, and recently killing about 4000 pilgrims during Haj. These are all obvious and has been announced world-wide.

So Why there is no action about them through UN or USA or 5+1 or other strong community in world. Why all of them are silent about them?

Comment: This question, at minimum, requires proof links for claims that (1) Saudi's actions take place; and (2) these actions are criminal; and also editing out offensive words.

Comment: @bytebuster "bastards" is an offensive word?

Comment: @bytebuster War is Yemen need any claim?? Did you hear abour Bahrain, they send military troops there. Killing 4000 pilgram in current Haj need any prove?? These are announced worldwide.

Comment: “Killing” implies intent, which is far from obvious and again inflammatory. War-mongering and the rest can certainly be criticised but it sounds like the kind of dirty politics many states engage in so again “criminal” isn't really the right category. There is no need to argue whether all this is good or bad, you can hate it and yet ask about the geopolitics using more neutral language. And I am sure that you know it yourself, so it's your choice: Either you want to ask a question and you drop the name-calling or you rant and try to make a point, in which case the question should be closed.

Comment: @Relaxed If you believe it's not a crime then prove it. Why should you speak of closing this question. If I'm wrong ,others can prove it here that I'm wrong, it is the basis of a question I think.

Comment: @HOPE I just explained to you why that is beside the point. I emphatically do not want to prove it one way or the other. And the reason why it's not meaningful to call all this a crime, is not because it's justifiable or anything, but simply because criminal law exist within the context of a state and apply to individuals. There is no criminal law for states, it's an error of category. You're not even wrong, it's meaningless, it only makes sense as a deliberately inflammatory criticism, not to discuss politics dispassionately.

Comment: Also, no it's not the basis of the question as I understood it, it even seems completely incidental to it, you might just as well ask “Why is Saudi Arabia allowed to intervene in Bahrain or Yemen or support this or that group without international pushback?” without ever using words like “bastards” or “criminal”. It's the same question, only without loaded, empty labels.

Comment: @HOPE Re: *„If you believe it's not a crime then prove it“*, this is not how Q&A sites work. **You** started the original question, so **you** prove your claim first.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, well yes. If the OP meant to say, [*„a person born of unmarried parents“*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bastard) then genealogy of an undefined group of people would be offtopic of Politics.SE. Maybe, Genealogy.SE? :-)

Comment: @bytebuster I've been proved some of my statements if you have attention to my post. War in Yemen, Bahrain and current Haj. Killing innocent people, is a Crime, from whoever want it to be. Isn't starting a war a Criminal action, in your idea? Does it need PROOF?!

Comment: @HOPE The whole notion of a "criminal" action doesn't really apply to states. There is no international criminal law that applies to sovereigns.

Comment: Saudi Arabia is a Western country, the International Community usually does not take actions against Western countries.

Comment: I'm putting a -1 because this question has so many mistakes, that could be avoided if the OP take the [Politics.SE tour](http://politics.stackexchange.com/tour). Currently ISIS is self-financed using the oil well taken during their operations, smuggling and taxes imposed by the Sharia. I'm not informed that Saudi Arabia is financing ISIS. Do you have any proof?

Comment: @nelruk yet they supply weapons, such as TOWs to the other Syrian rebels.

Comment: @nelruk Military supply is an undeniable parts of Saudi aids to ISIS.

Answer (score 8):

KSA is protected by their wealth in the international community. West is highly dependent on Saudi petroleum products and US especially considers geographical and strategic importance of Saudia vital to their interests in the region.

In the region itself which is populated mainly by Sunni Muslims, Saudia is revered just for the fact that they hold the two holy cities of Mecca and Medina. General populace never believes anything bad about them and considers them just as holy. An attack on them will be considered an attack on Islam itself by many, creating a very dangerous situation.

Iran and Turkey are no saints either. Turkey under the leadership of Recep Tayep Erodgan is not the Turkey that we know. They are [actively involved](http://www.hurriyetdailynews.com/the-desperate-alliance-of-turkey-and-saudi-arabia.aspx?PageID=238&NID=95162&NewsCatID=406) in Saudi led fanatic alliances. Iran is well Iran, [twin sister of KSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_and_state-sponsored_terrorism) but [less uglier](https://www.hrw.org/world-report/2014/country-chapters/iran).

As for UN, it is a puppet organization, what do you expect them to do? Recently KSA got a seat in the [UN human rights entity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Human_Rights_Council). A Saudi Ambassador has been elected chair of the Human Rights Council with [of course help of the UK](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/uk-and-saudi-arabia-made-secret-deal-to-exchange-votes-for-human-rights-council-seats-leaked-a6673491.html). As Hillel Neuer [puts it](https://www.yahoo.com/news/u-n-watchdog-slams-scandalous-160650242.html?ref=gs):

> It is scandalous that the UN chose a country that has beheaded more
>   people this year than ISIS to be head of a key human rights panel.
>   Petro-dollars and politics have trumped human rights.

Justice is for poor, losers and the weak. Rich, victors and strong always get away with everything. It's always been this way.

Nazis got Nuremberg trials for their crimes but were the Allies ever tried for [Dresden bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombing_of_Dresden_in_World_War_II), [hamburg bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firestorm), [Battle for Berlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape_during_the_occupation_of_Germany#Soviet_Military), [Japanese nuclear massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_bombings_of_Hiroshima_and_Nagasaki)?

Saddam got hanged for his crimes but did his [US mates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_war_crimes) got the same?

Serbian President faced war crimes tribunals for Bosnia but will NATO face the same for [Serbian TV bombing raid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_bombing_of_the_Radio_Television_of_Serbia_headquarters)? Will Barack Obama answer for [drone murders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civilian_casualties_from_US_drone_strikes) and recent [hospital bombing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunduz_hospital_airstrike)?

It's always been this way.

Comment: I like your answer , its realistic. as you state no country is saint all care about its self .

Comment: Good explanation, you stated real world, where rules are controlled by those who are stronger. Realistic view.

Answer (score 0):

there is a [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidents_during_the_Hajj) explain on general incidents happend in hajj. through hajj history many incident happend

> July 2, 1990: A stampede inside a pedestrian tunnel (Al-Ma'aisim tunnel) leading out from Mecca towards Mina and the Plains of Arafat
>   led to the deaths of 1,426 pilgrims, many of them of Malaysian,
>   Indonesian and Pakistani origin.[2][3]
>
> May 23, 1994: A stampede killed at least 270 pilgrims at the stoning of the Devil ritual.
>
> April 9, 1998: at least 118 pilgrims were trampled to death and 180 injured in an incident on Jamarat Bridge.
>
> March 5, 2001: 35 pilgrims were trampled to death in a stampede during the stoning of the Devil ritual.
>       February 11, 2003: The stoning of the Devil ritual claimed 14 pilgrims' lives.
>   February 1, 2004: 251 pilgrims were killed and another 244 injured in a stampede during the stoning ritual in Mina.
>
> January 12, 2006: A stampede during the stoning of the Devil on the last day of the Hajj in Mina killed at least 346 pilgrims and
>   injured at least 289 more. The incident occurred shortly after 13:00
>   local time, when a busload of travellers arrived together at the
>   eastern access ramps to the Jamarat Bridge. This caused pilgrims to
>   trip, rapidly resulting in a lethal stampede. An estimated two million
>   people were performing the ritual at the time.
>
> September 24, 2015: More than 1200 pilgrims were killed and another 950 injured during a stampede in the 2015 Hajj. The death toll
>   could still rise since there are about 1250 missing pilgrims and some
>   of the injured are not expected to recover[8] Iranian state controlled
>   media, Press TV claims that the Saudi Vice Minister of Health has said
>   than 4,173 people died in this incident, However, there was no press
>   release or an official statement by The Saudi Health Minister
>   regarding this matter, Press TV also claims that The Saudi Health
>   Ministry later denied the reports, Although they were never contacted
>   for confirmation.

many islamic state such as [turkey](http://www.todayszaman.com/anasayfa_ak-party-official-urges-saudi-to-hand-over-hajj-management-to-turkey_399931.html) and iran demand hajj managment by all islamic countries. but offource saudi arabia will not accept easily

Comment: tnx for your complete explanation of what resume of Saudis for Haj. You see, this time it's not pilgrims mistakes, it was exactly because of Saudi actions.